# Is there a way to perform a branch of jQuery chaining only if a condition is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements

I'm probably about a 7 or 8 on proficiency with jQuery (on a scale of 1-10), so I'm not sure if this even makes sense, but I'd like to know if anyone knows of a jQuery function or possibly a plugin which allows a branch of jQuery to only be executed if a given condition is true. Otherwise, I'd love to hear if someone thinks the concept is flawed in some way (**EDIT** and *how* it is flawed)

While one could control attachment of various events using normal JavaScript syntax similar to this:

```
var desiredElement = $('.parent')                        // find the parent element
                     .hover(overFunction,offFunction)    // attach an event while I've got the parent in 'scope'
                     .find('.child-element');            // then find and return the child
if (booleanVar1) {                                       // if one condition
    desiredElement.click(clickFunction1);                //   attach one event
} else if (booleanVar2) {                                // or if a different condition
    desiredElement.click(clickFunction2);                //   attach a different event
} else {                                                 // otherwise
    desiredElement.click(clickFunction3);                //   attach a default event
}
$('.parent').find('.other-child')                        // (or $('.parent .other-child')
    .css(SomePredefinedCssMapping)
    .hide()
//...
```

I was wondering if there is a way to do it all in jQuery or if there is a good reason not to... something perhaps like this:

```
$('.parent')                                // find the parent element
    .hover({overFunction,offFunction})      // attach an event while I've got the parent in 'scope'
    .find('.child-element')                 // then find the child
        .when(booleanVar1)                  // if one condition
            .click(clickFunction1)          //   attach one event
        .orWhen(booleanVar2)                // or if a different condition
            .click(clickFunction2)          //   attach a different event
        .orElse()                           // otherwise
            .click(clickFunction3)          //   attach a default event
        .end()
    .end()
    .find('.other-child')
        .css(SomePredefinedCssMapping)
//...
```

*Note: I think this is syntactically correct, assuming the booleans and functions are defined appropriately, but I'm pretty sure I've gotten the intent across pretty clearly*

the proposed jQuery seems a little neater to me (??) agree/disagree? - so here are my questions:

- Is there some part of native jQuery that basically already does this?
- Is there an extension already out there that allows this type of thing?
- Is it harder to do than I am thinking? (I'd think something like keeping the current element set if the condition is true, pushing an empty element set if condition is false, then popping the element set back out for each `or` condition would do it, just like the `end()` method pops back the previous set after a `find()` call)
- Is there something that makes it significantly less efficient?

**EDIT**

The question asks how to do this with method chaining or why it would be unadvisable (specifics preferred). While it doesn't ask for alternatives, such alternatives might be necessary to explain problems with a jQuery chaining approach. Also, since the example above immediately evaluates the booleans, any other solution should do the same.

Comment: There is definitely a plugin for it somewhere, I've seen it posted as an answer in the jQuery forums before. I don't agree with this kind of syntax though, it is adding in more function calls for something that doesn't necessarily make coding easier.

Comment: while I appreciate EVERYONE's commentary (especially @tereško - though I'm not sure I agree), I'm still not seeing an actual answer to any of my questions, so I'm gonna hold out a while longer

Comment: are you unaware that method chaining is harmful practice ?

Comment: @tereško - I am unaware of how it would be harmful, though I could imagine it might not be the best solution. how is it harmful? potentially unstable? inefficient? if inefficient, then to approximately what degree? -- in terms of efficiency, how does one measure the tradeoff of development time vs. program efficiency? Aren't all high-level languages (especially non-compiled languages) less efficient than byte code? they are definitely much easier to write!

Comment: @tereško - if method chaining is 'harmful practice', then may I presume you do not use jQuery at all? Unless I miss my guess, nothing can be done in jQuery without using *some* amount of method chaining. Is there a particular threshold or limit to the use of chaining beyond which it becomes significantly more harmful? as for inefficiency, the very concept of frameworks and/or code reuse often necessitates these inefficiencies

Comment: @KevinB (sorry, but noone else seems to feel strongly enough to explain) Anyone wanna chime in on _why_ this is "horrifying" - apparently quite a few people think so - I did find a plugin that does precisely this and I would appreciate an explanation for _why_ it is not a good idea - this doesn't compare to "adding with jQuery" either, as adding has nothing to do with program flow or selecting DOM elements - seriously, come up with a less absurdly inaccurate comparison.

Comment: @CodeJockey -- Can you help me? I can't think of a good coding scenario to compare using this type of method vs the usual way you would do it. In every way that i come up with, the other way is leaps and bounds more efficient than using an if/then/else plugin. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @KevinB how about something like `...find('a.external').when(AlertOnExternalLinksBool).click(AlertExternalLinkFunction).else().hover(addExtLinkWarning,removeExtLinkWarning).end()` would be a reasonable example. Anyone that concerned with having incredibly efficient code should probably make sure they couldn't just use `document.getElementById()` or `document.getElementsByTagName()` and looping through to find a node with a given class... because that's much more efficient, isn't it?

Comment: In this example, is `AlertOnExternaLinksBool` a settings object set somewhere in an object? Also, I don't think `.when` will ever be used by the jquery core in this context due to it being used with deferred objects and the confusion that .load and .load have caused.

Comment: @KevinB [Let's continue this in a chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10755/conditional-method-chaining-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.parent').hover(overFunction,offFunction)
    .find('.child-element')
    .click( booleanVar ? clickFunction1 :
            booleanVar2 ? clickFunction2 :
            clickFunction3 )
    .end()
    .find('.other-child')
    .css(SomePredefinedCssMapping)
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems closer in spirit to what I was hoping to find, and might be good enough to work. I believe I had avoided this tactic because a similar attempt messed up css selectors in "associative arrays" (like where `...css({(boolVar?"left":"right"):"30px"})` causes an error). It should have immediate evaluation of the booleans but still is not quite as "pretty" as I _think_ jQuery chaining would be - assuming it works, and there's no better answer, I'll accept it at some point

Comment: @CodeJockey Right. That's because it's syntactically invalid ([reference](http://es5.github.com#x11.1.5)). This code works as you intend in the OP, and is far more concise as well.

Comment: @CodeJockey btw, `.hover({overFunction,offFunction})` is syntactically invalid (It appears in your OP, I have edited it to working code in my answer)

Comment: good point about the `.hover({...`. I think I was confused due to the use of {} in defining the two functions inline (like `.hover(function(){....}`) -- is there a similar syntax to the css call above that is valid but combines the "associate array" concept of the `.css({'left':'30px', 'top':'-5px'})` type of syntax with the expression support of the `.css((boolVar?'left':'right'),'30px')` syntax (which would allow me to add multiple css mappings in a single statement? (something like `.css({(boolVar?'left':'right'):'30px','top':'-5px','color':'red'})`) ??

Comment: @CodeJockey No because the language doesn't allow it. The closest you can get is: `.css( new function() {
 this[boolVar?'left':'right'] = 30;
 this.top = -5;
 this.color = "red";
})`. But this should be a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you perform that conditional logic within your handler?

```
var boolVar1 = true,
    boolVar2 = false;

$(".foo").on("click", function(){
  if ( boolVar1 ) clickFunction1();
  if ( boolVar2 ) clickFunction2();
});
```

Comment: First thanks for your response - I had not considered this - While I don't mind a small amount of "pure" JavaScript (it should, after all, be more efficient - right?) the question specifically queries the use of jQuery chaining - either native jQuery, a plugin, or some reason it's harder to do or significantly a bad idea to do on my own. Also the question has a strong implication of _immediate_ evaluation of the boolean variables, not delayed until the click event occurs - if the variables change for any reason prior to the click, this will change the behavior - I'll edit to make this explicit

Comment: @rlemon - I appreciate that jQuery is a library and that the `$()` function does a lot of things. The "development time / efficiency" trade off is always a reasonable thing to consider and in the elementary OP example, there is not a huge difference in development time - perhaps that is why they did not add it to jQuery (not enough of a savings to justify the extra processing needed?) That, however, is not part of this answer, and this answer will behave differently than the code in the question on a fundamental level.

Comment: It's like http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif come true. Seriously, what you want can be done with `?:` operator, like adding numbers can be done with `+` operator, you don't need a jQuery plugin for it.

Comment: yes - I thought that was pretty clear - an ability to insert conditionals into a jQuery method chain without losing the jQuery selector "context" and not having to worry about storing it in a variable temporarily - funny pic though... not sure how you'd add a number with jQuery or even go about designing that... hmmm.... :) -- the ternary `?:` operator was used in the other answer - feel free to upvote it if you think it's the best way to go

Comment: @CodeJockey You could always add with `$.add(5, 2)`. The point here is that doing something like this is largely unnecessary.

Comment: @Jonathan: Please tell me you're kidding and that there isn't *really* a jQuery function to add numbers. :(

Comment: @ElliotBonneville There isn't (I hope). My point was that somebody could make one if they wanted, but that wouldn't be necessary since the task is trivial.

Comment: Okay, good. You had me worried there for a second. Ontopic: @Code Jockey, what you're doing is like attempting to use a plastic toy that came out of a mold to make another plastic toy-- why not just use the original mold? (in this case, Javascript)